# Relocate contents of dynamic folder

Tags: ant, rename, move

I have a zip file which has one base folder inside it with other content inside that.  I don't always know what that base folder is going to be called until I unzip it.

I'd like to move that base folder, and rename it at the same time, in ant - but can't seem to find out how.  I've written code to extract the contents of the zip file to `${local.sdk.dir}/temp/` but from here i can't work out how to rename/move the extracted folder

```
<move todir="${local.sdk.dir}/${remote.sdk.file.name}">
  <fileset dir="${local.sdk.dir}/temp/<WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE?>"></fileset>
</move>
```

also tried

```
<move todir="${local.sdk.dir}/${remote.sdk.file.name}" includeEmptyDirs="yes" verbose="true">
  <fileset dir="${local.sdk.dir}/temp/" >
     <include name="**/*" />
  </fileset>
</move>
```

and played about with this, but closest I can get without ant throwing an error is to copy the contents of the temp dir, not the base folder within temp.

Comment: Why do you keep writing tags in titles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all this in one step - copy from the zip file and rename the files changing the dir name as you copy. The [`copy` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) accepts a nested [resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection), so you can use a [`zipfileset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) to specify the files to copy directly from the zip file.

In order to rename the files as they are copied, you can use a [mapper](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html), which the `copy` task also takes as a nested element. In this case, a [`cutsdirmapper`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#cutdirs-mapper) looks like the tool for the job.

So, if I've understood what you want to do correctly, something like this should work:

```
<copy todir="${local.sdk.dir}/${remote.sdk.file.name}">
  <zipfileset src="${your.zip.file}" />
  <cutdirsmapper dirs="1" />
</copy>
```

`cutdirsmapper` is only available in Ant 1.8.2 onward, so if you're using an earlier version, you could try a [`regexpmapper`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html#regexp-mapper):

```
<regexpmapper from="[^/]*(.*)" to="\1" />
```

Comment: that's a much better solution and saved me about 20 lines - thank you

Comment: One thing I've noticed about this approach is that it takes a much longer time to unpack the archive compared to my answer below - over 30 mins, compared to 1.5 minutes.

Comment: For what it's worth, the `<regexpmapper>` element works just as well as a child of an `<unzip>` task, which may well be clearer than a `<copy>` over a `<zipfileset>`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587048/using-ant-rename-a-directory-without-knowing-the-full-path)

```
  <target name="relocate_sdk_folder">     
    <path id="sdk_folder_name">
      <dirset dir="${local.sdk.dir}/temp/">
        <include name="*"/>
      </dirset>
    </path>
    <property name="sdk_folder_name" refid="sdk_folder_name" />
    <echo message="renaming ${sdk_folder_name} to ${remote.sdk.file.name}" />
    <move file="${sdk_folder_name}" tofile="${local.sdk.dir}/${remote.sdk.file.name}" />         
</target>
```